# Files stored in directory is returning empty?

Tags: java, android

I have  downloaded the image file and saved in a directory but it returning empty list files . Files are downloaded and stored in directory. I tried many solutions still it not solved. I am working on oreo devices and checked the runtime permission.

The below line is for checking the files inside the directory

```
 try{

                    File giftFolder = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/SamplePhoto/");
                    if (!giftFolder.exists()) {
                        giftFolder.mkdir();
                    }

                    File directory = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/SamplePhoto/");

                    if(directory.isDirectory()){
                        Log.d("Files", "directory: "+ directory.isDirectory());
                    }
                    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
                    Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                    {
                        Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The below code is for downloading file using download manger

```
public static  void downloadFile(Context context, String url, String fileName) {
        DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        downloadRequest.setTitle(fileName);

        // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            downloadRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }

        File giftFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/SamplePhoto");
        if (!giftFolder.exists()) {
            giftFolder.mkdir();
        }

    //    downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/SamplePhoto/", fileName);
     //   downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
        downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(context.getFilesDir() + "/SamplePhoto/", fileName);

        Log.e("DownloadingPath",""+ context.getFilesDir() + "/SamplePhoto/"+ fileName);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(downloadRequest);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
File giftFolder = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/SamplePhoto/");
```

To

```
File giftFolder = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/SamplePhoto");
```

And anywhere else you use `"/SamplePhoto/"` too. You dont need the tailing slash when accessing a directory.